# Wrong URL after migration of categories and products

Tags: magento-1.9, migration, base-url

I have just installed a fresh Magento (1.9.0.1) in a sub directory of existing installation. They do not share DB. While i am setting up this new webshop i suddenly notice that "default" is added in the URL.

I can access the new site fine without "default" in the URL, but after visiting category or product page, this is added in URL :(

Existing site:

```
www.mysite.com
```

New site:

```
www.mysite.com/new
```

Actual URL of new installation after visiting category or product page

```
www.mysite.com/new/default
```

Old installation and new installation do not share anything but i have transferred products to new site using cart2cart service.

I have checked unsecure and secure URL in DB and this is set correct to www.mysite.com/new

What am i missing here and why is "default" added in the URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try checking if the option "Add Store Code to URLs" is enabled in your Magento Admin --> System --> Configuration --> Web.

If it is enabled, you should disable it and it will resolve the issue.

The reason it adds "default" to the end of your URL is because by default Magento's default store is called "default".